# Как вывести html с input?

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать чтобы html код, который введен в поле, выводился правильно, то есть текст стал жирным?

[image: Отображение]

```
function test() {
    var e = document.getElementById('p_desc');
    var text = e.innnerHtml;
    document.getElementById('test').innerHtml = text;
}
```

Comment: Не надо после получения ответа изменять вопрос!

Comment: Сделал как надо сами смотрите

Comment: @5grrthrthrh, если возник новый вопрос - задайте его как новый вопрос, а не редактируйте этот. При необходимости добавьте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для `input` вместо `innerHTML` используется `value` или `contenteditable` для остальных типа `div`

```js
var  e = document.getElementById('p_desc');
 var txt = e.value;
function test()
{
  txt = e.value;
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = txt;
}
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener("click", test);
```

```css
* {
font-family:sans-serif;

}
#p_desc {
padding:5px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
margin:0;
outline:0;
transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
min-width:155px;
max-width:155px;
}

#p_desc:focus {
box-shadow:0 0 10px #27A6FF;
}
#submit {
padding:5px;
border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
background:white;
border:1px solid #ccc;
margin:0;
cursor:pointer;

width:100%;
}
br{
margin:0;
}
#cont {
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
<textarea id="p_desc" name="p_desc" ></textarea>
<br>
<button id="submit">Отправить</button>
</div>
<pre id="test"></pre>
```

Comment: Всмысле Inline JS?

Comment: onkeypress="test()"

Comment: он вроде не в одну линию

Comment: а ну если так то

Comment: все исправил...

Comment: Спросите у автора вопроса

Comment: Используется textarea когда я перехожу на новую строку и пишу текст он выводится в одну линию ! Как исправить??

Comment: HTML: <textarea onkeyup="test();" id="p_desc"></textarea>

Comment: function test()
{
    var e = document.getElementById('p_desc');
    var text =  e.value;
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = text;
}

Comment: @Duoxx в текущем варианте нужно не забыть уточнить, что код должен либо идти после появления элемента в DOM, либо быть обёрнут в document ready. Это во-первых. Во-вторых, `.onchange` не сильно лучше варианта с inline JS. По-хорошему, стоит использовать `addEventListener`.

Comment: Поправил_______

Comment: Изменил на addEventListener

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь!